# ReactJS: How to parse response of files sent from REST API and display them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

Using ReactJS, I have a GET request working with fetch method, and the REST API responds with a few files. How would they be sent to me?

Meaning, can it be parsed with response.json(), so that it can be displayed as actual files from REST API and also be downloaded to local drive?

**Here is the method that makes the GET request:**

```
  sendFileRequest() {

      ...

      return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_API'
      });

      return fetch('http://11.22.33.44:8080/receive/files', getRequest)
      .then(response => response.json()) //Could I do .json() with files being the response?
      .then(APIfiles => {
        //How can I parse the files returned and display them for download to local drive?
      })
  }
```

Comment: you basically mean the response from ur api is file or json text?

Comment: You can use JSON.parse(response) , Can you post your api response so that we can get a better idea

Comment: @MyMasterPeice Will be file

Comment: @LionelDcosta sorry but typically in what response form is file in?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch({}).then(res => res.json())` or `fetch({}).then(res => res.text())`, it depend on the content-type of your response.

if your contentType is `application/json`, you should use `res.json()`,

if your contentType is `text/plain`, you should use `res.text()`.

you can check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) here.

Since your server just return a file, I think you should use `res.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the likely response content-type with the one who is responsible for developing the API.

What you need to know is that REST is not fastened to JSON. It is all about resources, therefore, you may receive XML, plain text, files, etc.